# Epiphone SG-400 and straps

Tags: guitar, equipment

New owner of an Epiphone SG-400 and obviously beginner at playing guitar, I am somehow surprised to see that unlike the guitars I have so far been able to touch, the strap "hook" on the neck side is place right behind the it([as seen here](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_bFuRFEdeTvs/S9L1VMRBDYI/AAAAAAAAAx8/RMt7L1STMEQ/s1600/Epi+SG400+04.jpg)), and not on top of the guitar ([like seen here](http://www.musictheorymadesimple.com/Images/girlguitar.png)).

As a consequence, I can't get the guitar to place properly as it tends to place itself horizontaly, while I'd like it a bit inclined...

Question is: is it my strap that is not adapted or is it more a general problem or thing to get used to with the SG-400?

Is there a way to move the hook higher or would that ruin sound or something else?

Answer (score 7):

The Epiphone SG-400 has terrible balance.

I got my Epiphone SG because I wanted a dedicated slide guitar - ala Derek Trucks. But with slide, you don't support the neck with your left hand - so I found this guitar impossible to play as the neck kept falling.

Basically, this strap has lead weights in it which fix the balance issue. Once you have it balanced, the guitar feels awesome to play again.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem with my Firebird. In general, it's something you'll likely have to just get used to. It gets more fun if you use strap-locks because you have to install one of the strap buttons backwards.

It's really not that bad once you get used to it, especially with a neck heavy guitar like a Firebird.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to move the strap button.

Be sure to drill a small pilot hole at the new, desired location first though, to avoid splitting the wood. Fill the old hole with some spackle, and then touch up the spot with some crayon (to colour-match) and then buff some wax over the area nicely.

It's your guitar, and it should hang from your body in a manner that pleases you, and in an ergonomically-correct fashion that facilitates a comfortable performance.